# Fill javascript array with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How Can i fill an array that defined in javascript with c# in behind code?

EDIT:

here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
string[] locations = new string[] {
    "Las Vegas",
    "Los Angeles",
    "Tampa",
    "New York",
    "s",
    "sss"
};
string jsArray = GetJSArrayForVBArray(locations);
this.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("usernames", jsArray);
}

private string GetJSArrayForVBArray(string[] vbArray)
{
StringBuilder myResult = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in Constants.vbArray) {
    {
        myResult.Append(",'" + item + "'");
    }
}
if ((myResult.Length > 0)) {
    return myResult.ToString().Substring(1);
} else {
    return "";
}
}
```

Javsacript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var usernames = new Array();
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: usernames
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Generate a javascript code block to do it. `someArray.push(someValue)`.

Comment: Also, check if you can accept a few answers to your earlier questions.  Asking questions and not coming back to them is rude.

Comment: what is the problem with syntax highlighter?
@tomalak ???????????
@ Jaroslav Jandek : thanks. give me a link for more information or an example
@oded edited

Comment: @shaahin: I don't think that there are simpler words to explain it. Read my comment again if you don't understand it.

Comment: @Tomalak: I did that.
Thanks For your advice :) .

Comment: @shaahin: That's a bit better already. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class. Something like the following should do it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string[] locations = new string[] {
        "Las Vegas",
        "Los Angeles",
        "Tampa",
        "New York",
        "s",
        "sss"
    };

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string jsArray = serializer.Serialize(locations);
    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "locations", jsArray, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
how can i use it in my aspx page?

Comment: I cant use array in aspx page.
please help me.
i used this code.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var locations= new Array();
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: locations
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: @shaahin - what doe my code output to the page? There's no need to declare a new JavaScript array to hold the values that we are outputting from the server side, we just need to assign what we output to a variable and then assign that variable value to the source property of the object that you're passing to autocomplete

Comment: Alternatively, you could write the result of calling serialize straight into the aspx markup, using `<%= ... %>` tags

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Note that if you scroll down on that page you'll see a number of resources for utilizing JSON in C#. It's really a great way to transfer data back and forth between various platforms/languages.

Comment: Well, check out the links listed on that page. Most of the work for 'converting' is done for you by one of those packages, depending on your implementation. Specifically, it becomes a matter of basically calling JsonEncode/JsonDecode (or using helper functions to work with specific collection types) with the code at: http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/618/news/view/14605/14863/How-do-I-write-my-own-parser-for-JSON.html